# Broken packages - linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic not installed

Tags: package-management

When I try to install packages or updates I receive this error:

```
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic :
Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic but it is not installed
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu SE.  Feel free to take the tour at https://askubuntu.com/Tour that will help you get the most from this site.  Specifically, to attract the best answers we'll need more information.  Please show what you have tried that generated this error message.

Comment: What is the exact response to: `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic` ? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: when I try to install anything using sudo apt-get install i received that message

Comment: What's your Ubuntu release (see the output of `lsb_release -a` if unsure)? Could you please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of `sudo apt-get install -f linux-image-generic`? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS Xenial 
I Type: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic` but i received a message `The following packages have unmet dependencies: linux-generic: Depends: linux-headers-generic (= 4.4.4.0.109.114) but 4.4.0.119.125 is to be installed` and `linux-headers-generic: Depends: Linux-headers-4.4.0.119 but is is not going to be installed`

Comment: @DavidFoerster Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS Xenial

Comment: I need the ***full, verbatim output*** of the Apt command! Also could you please [edit] your post when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: In any case I believe that the answers to the [linked duplicate question](/q/2793/175814) will solve your issue.